# How to notify user that new data is avalable so that they need to refresh?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm working  on a news app. I fetch data from server directly in JSON format, parse it and show in views. I would like to be able to be able to notfify the use that new data is avaible and they need to refresh instead of automatically updating.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: you can use firebase messaging/notifications for that

Comment: That would send notifications to the user? I'm more on a simple snackbar  that show when user is using the app and  a listener that triggers the refresh

Comment: then you can use a thread that runs in the background or take a look at work manager, it runs in the background and using that you can notify user to refresh the data ?.

Comment: That seems good. But how to know that the JSON  response I'm receiving has new data, not the previously fetched data?

Comment: Once new data is available, you send data message (fcm), on receiving send a local broadcast to the receiver on the screen, if it is registered, refresh the screen/show snackbar with refresh action. Or else show a notification with a constant notification I'd so upcoming refresh notification gets updated instead added in notification bar. On clicking of that redirect to screen and you get the refreshed content.

Comment: @mnp343 thenks for your explaination

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to compare the json data string value to the new value from the server. Something like this:

```
if (currentJSONDataString != newJSONDataString) {
Toast.make(context, “Updates available. Please refresh”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

The limitation here though is that this only checks to see if your current data differs in any way from the server data. If you had things in your data model such as a datetime field that indicated the last updated at time or something similar you could do a more accurate comparison to check if the current data is before the newer data.

Comment: In my "article" I have 2 datetime fields (the time the zrticle was created and the time it was modified)

Comment: @Krul I don’t think that’s useful in a list view. It will only work for already downloaded articles/in an article details view and not do a check against new ones on a list. I think what you’re looking to do is setup a timer and fetch data in the background then do a comparison against said data. If there’s a difference show your snackbar.